# jQuery .find() method - searching within string converted to jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var myHTML = '<div class="mapInfoWindow"><p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p><p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p><p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p><p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p></div><div class="mapInfoWindow"><p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p><p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p><p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p><p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p></div><div class="mapInfoWindow"><p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p><p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p><p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p><p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p></div>';

var obj = $(myHTML).get(0);
var totalCount = $(obj).find('.infoWindowParagraph').length;

console.log('Total p.infoWindowParagraph tags in the FIRST mapInfoWindow div is : ' + totalCount);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So I have a HTML string that is similar to the following, and I'm trying to get a count of the `.infoWindowParagraph` tags in the FIRST `.mapInfoWindow` div.  For whatever reason, it's not working as I expect and I'm not sure why.

**HTML**

```
<div class="mapInfoWindow">
    <p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p>
    <p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p>
    <p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p>
    <p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p>    
</div>
<div class="mapInfoWindow">
    <p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p>
    <p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p>
    <p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p>
    <p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p>    
</div>
<div class="mapInfoWindow">
    <p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p>
    <p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p>
    <p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p>
    <p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p>    
</div>
```

**jQuery/JavaScript**

```
var testObj = $([string from above]);
console.log(testObj.find('.mapInfoWindow').find('.infoWindowParagraph').length);

-- returns 0 every time should return 4
-- also tried below trying to focus on first index (first instance of mapInfoWindow div in object returned)

var testObj = $([string from above]).get(0).find('.infoWindowParagraph').length);

-- still returns 0
```

**update**

Well damn, I got it working now.  Sorry SO for the time-wasting here, overlooked the obvious!

Comment: I'm guessing the error might be related to `$([string from above])`, could you please post that selector and a little more of the surrounding html please?

Comment: And if you do that, you could create a StackSnippet on the fly...

Comment: @Hodrobond - I have the HTML string in my question in a javascript variable, and I simply create the jQuery object from that variable using $(myvariable);

Comment: Your updated question appears to print `4` from the first snippet, isn't that the expected behavior? Apologies, i'm not understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
var testObj = '<div class="mapInfoWindow"><p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p><p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p><p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p><p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p></div><div class="mapInfoWindow"><p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p><p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p><p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p><p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p></div><div class="mapInfoWindow"><p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p><p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p><p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p><p class="infoWindowParagraph">DATA HERE</p></div>';

console.log($(testObj).first('.mapInfoWindow').children('.infoWindowParagraph').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are trying to select ".mapInfoWindow" and that is the actual object, you can only do .find() on descendants nodes.

Try:`testObj.find('.infoWindowParagraph').length`

That will work!